# Configure Ubuntu with 3 NICs as gateway/router

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, dhcp, router

I have a PC with Ubuntu 14.04, which I'm trying to configure as a gateway/router for my LAN. The topology is as below:

[Network topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9Mvd.png)

I'm configuring 1 subnet only - eth0 and eth3 will both be connected to the same local subnet.

The Ubuntu router has dhcp3-server installed and running. The 2 PCs are able to get IP addresses assigned (as shown in the figure).

Currently, I have the following problems/issues/questions:

- My /etc/network/interfaces file content is below - is it correct? I think assigning 192.168.1.1 to both eth3 and eth0 looks strange, but I cannot figure out what's other options.

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth2
  iface eth2 inet dhcp

  auto eth3
  iface eth3 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  network 192.168.1.0

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  network 192.168.1.0
  ```
- Neither of the 2 PCs can ping each other, nor can they ping the ubuntu router at 192.168.1.1. Why? (I have enabled ipv4 forwarding in the router)
- I think one Ubuntu machine can be configured to have one gateway only, right? In the ubuntu router, eth2 already has a gateway that is assigned to it by ISP through DHCP. Do I need to / how do I configure gateway for the other 2 NICs?

Comment: I have spent the last 4 hours Google'ing for an answer, but most of the posts I found have 1 NIC for WAN and 1 NIC for LAN. I cannot find how to configure multiple local NIC's IP addresses.

Comment: Tip:  eth0 should be your WAN/default route to the Internet

Comment: I'd recommend that you set up the single LAN NIC.  Once that's working, you should be able to replicate the process for the second NIC.

Comment: Tip: Two machines (or NICS) on the same network should *not* have the same IP.  If you think that you need this, you should look into *bonding*.

Comment: If you're using `dhcpd`, you should be able to 'push routes' and networking information, such as subnet masks, dns providers and gateways.